# Third party Visual Studio snippets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

Do you know where I could find some useful third party (free) code snippets for VS 2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://gotcodesnippets.com/
http://www.codekeep.net/ has a VS add-in for their snippets, too

Answer (score 2):

bdukes site has more options, but here are the ones MSDN has published...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718338.aspx